# git pull - Already Up To Date

Tags: git

I am using GIT to synchronize source code files between my desktop computer and my server.

I have a git repository on the server which I created with `git init --bare`. I then created a repository on my desktop using `git init` and the added all the code files with `git add ... etc...`.

I then added the server repo as "an origin" (whatever that means - what's the difference between origin and master? These kind of seem like 2 random or arbitrary labels.) using this command: `git remote add origin ssh://put the server url here (192.168.0.1 blaa blaa etc)`

I ran `git push origin master` on the desktop side. This send the code to the git repository on the server.

However I need to compile my code on the server. In order to do that I cloned the git repository into an adjacent directory on the server. (server side:) (make new directory in same directory as parent of git repository, cd to this new directory) `git clone ../gitrespository.git` (makes a new subdir with my code)

I can then cd to this subdirectory to compile and run.

However I have now made some changes to my code. I removed a file from the git tracking on the desktop side, and then physically renamed this file. I also added a new file to the git tracking on the desktop side. I used `git push origin master` to push the code to the server.

However now when I run `git pull` on the server side, *inside the cloned repository* I just get a message saying "Already Up To Date". The new file is not shown and the old file I removed is still there... What am I doing wrong?

Finally, is there a better way of uploading my code to the server. I was using rsync to just copy it. Git has the advantage that it tracks changes (although I haven't learned how to do this yet) and allows multiple users to work on the code. This probably means I am less likely to make a serious mistake if I work with multiple computers (desktop / laptop on the go) if I use a git repository. The disadvantage however is that rsync is a lot "quicker". I run 1 command (as a shell script to reduce typing) to upload my code, and then another command on the server to compile. With Git I have to run 1 command to upload and then another to clone and then another to compile. I guess it's only 1 more command but still seems a bit "weird" to have the code stored in a repository in a format which I can't use on the server (not sure how Git repositories are formatted but they are not human readable as far as I can see) and then clone this code to another directory where it is in a format which I can compile...

Comment: Be sure That doing the push on desktop side after renamed and remove files doesn't display errors

Answer (score 0):

There is another command which must be run before running `git push origin master`. Run `git commit -m 'some message here'` before running.

This means that I must run twice as many commands as `rsync` however, which is slightly inconvenient...